# How do I deploy my cli program with custom library with visual studio for mac from the command line?

Tags: c#, .net, macos, visual-studio-mac

I am working on a Mac with Visual Studio Mac 8.1.4.5 (==latest) and macOS Mojave (==latest,too).

My boss told me to rewrite a simple windows cli program to become platform independent, so I wrote **a platform independent library (ez.login.eas.library.dll), a Mac cli program with mono (ez.login.eas.mac.exe) and a Windows cli program (ez.login.eas.win.exe)** and both are using the library.

The target framework for the library is .NET Standard 2.0, the Mac command line program is .NET Framework 4.7.2 and the Windows command line program is .NET Framework 4.7.2, too.

**Now I want to deploy my Mac cli program from within the command line.**

But I am no expert regarding .NET and the like. I am more a Xcode developer.

One of my colleagues told me that is was possible to "assemble" the cli program together with mono runtime libs and ez.login.eas.library by using something similar to

> dotnet build -c release -r

but this leads to 2 errors:

/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.700/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1175,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. [/Users/rwelz/Documents/Develop/PROJEKTE/ThinPrint/in GIT/ThinPrint/EZEEP for Azure/C#/ez.login.eas/ez.login.eas.mac/ez.login.eas.mac.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.700/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1175,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. [/Users/rwelz/Documents/Develop/PROJEKTE/ThinPrint/in GIT/ThinPrint/EZEEP for Azure/C#/ez.login.eas/ez.login.eas.win/ez.login.eas.win.csproj]
  ez.login.eas.library -> /Users/rwelz/Documents/Develop/PROJEKTE/ThinPrint/in GIT/ThinPrint/EZEEP for Azure/C#/ez.login.eas/ez.login.eas.library/bin/Release/netstandard2.0/osx/ez.login.eas.library.dll

Build FAILED.

/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.700/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1175,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. [/Users/rwelz/Documents/Develop/PROJEKTE/ThinPrint/in GIT/ThinPrint/EZEEP for Azure/C#/ez.login.eas/ez.login.eas.mac/ez.login.eas.mac.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.700/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1175,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. [/Users/rwelz/Documents/Develop/PROJEKTE/ThinPrint/in GIT/ThinPrint/EZEEP for Azure/C#/ez.login.eas/ez.login.eas.win/ez.login.eas.win.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)

**Actually I need the cli as Resource in a Mac Application bundle where the application launches the cli on demand. The cli does some network stuff and eventually opens the default webbrowser with a returned URL and then quits.**

So I need the CLI, the library (DLL?) and the mono runtime stuff in the Mac Application bundle.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Any idea how to deploy the complete visual studio for Mac cli app so I can simply copy everything into the Xcode release folder (the app's Resources folder)?

Comment: Issuing 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.18.1/bin/msbuild -r
in my project's folder does compile everything.

But to launch the cli program I have to issue
mono ez.login.eas.mac.exe -v

How do I include the mono binary so that my customers don't need to install visual studio or Xamarin on their Macs?

Comment: I found out that I can deploy a "self contained" application for applications built with .NET core only. But .NET core can not utilize mono. Did I miss anything? Platform independence is not given here so what's all the fuzz about it?

Comment: Did you try [mkbundle](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/mkbundle/)?

Comment: @Matt Ward: Great, thank you very much - yes, this was the right way to go: I had to copy netstandard.dll and OpenTK.dll in the Develop folder and issued mkbundle -o ez.login.eas.mac --simple ez.login.eas.mac.exe and had a binary which could be executed inside this Develop folder on another machine (without mono, Xamarin etc ever installed): ./ez.login.eas.mac I guess I could even add these dlls with the -library option of mkbundle.

Comment: Since mono is deprecated now (from microsoft) I my boss told me to use .NET core. This means instead of using NSUserDefaults I will store my data in a Json file, and for global data (for all users) I will store this json file in /Users/Shared/ This does not feel very Mac-like, but is imho the only way to store global config data without being root. :(